# Next.jsでTwitchの認証情報を利用してFirebase認証をしたい。

Tags: firebase, next.js

Next.jsでTwitchのOIDCを利用したFirebaseの認証をしたいと考えております。そこで、どのように実装すればいいのかアドバイスいただきたく投稿させていただきました。

色々調べてみたのですが、Google等のFirebaseでサポートされているIdPや単純なパスワード認証であればサンプルが見つかりますが、TwitchなどのサポートされていないIdPの場合の実装例を見つけることがで来ませんでした。

そこで以下のようにいくつか案を考えて少し実装してみましたがうまくいかずっておりません。アドバイスいただけますと幸いです。

1. FirebaseのOpenIDConnectorを利用する
   こちらはFirebaseとIdentity Platformを利用した方法ですが、Firebaseにカスタムプロバイダーを定義できるとのことですが、おそらくFirebaseエミュレータで動作させることができなく、料金も別途かかってしまうので保留としています。
2. Next.jsで独自にTwitchのOIDC認証を行いカスタムトークンからFirebaseを認証する。
   現状こちらの方法を利用しているのですが、Twitch認証を行った後Next.jsのCallbackのページにリダイレクトされ、そこからサーバサイド（Functions）にCodeを転送してアクセストークンを取得する仕様なのですが、リダイレクトされたときにページが3回ロードされているようで後ろ2回のロードではすでにCodeが利用できないためエラーとなってしまいます。こちらを抑制することはできるのでしょうか。
   ちなみに、アクセストークンをサーバで取得した後は以下の流れを実装する予定です。

・サーバサイドでユーザ作成
・カスタムトークン作成とクライアントへ返却
・クライアントでFirebaseの認証を行い、得られたCredentialをNext-authに渡す。

サインインページとリダイレクト先の実装は下記のとおりです。

app/signin/page.tsx

```
"use client";

export default function Home() {
  const twitchScope = "openid user:read:email";
  const twitchRedirectUri = "http://localhost:3000/callback";
  const clientId = "client_id";

  const url = `https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/authorize?client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(
    twitchRedirectUri
  )}&response_type=code&scope=${encodeURIComponent(twitchScope)}`;

  return (
    <main
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        height: "70vh",
      }}
    >
      <div>
        <a href={url}>Twitch login</a>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

app/callback/page.tsx

```
"use client";

import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";

export default function Home() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const code = searchParams.get("code");
  console.log(code);
  const twitchRedirectUri = "http://localhost:3000/callback";

  // アクセストークンを取得するためのFunctionsのエンドポイントへコードを送信。ここが3回呼ばれるためエラーになる。
  fetch(
    `http://localhost:5001/project_id/us-central1/authenticate_with_twitch?code=${code}&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(
      twitchRedirectUri
    )}`
  ).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  });

  return <main></main>;
}
```

質問としては2点ありまして、
1つはそもそもこのフロー以外に方法はないのか。
初めの段階ではNext-AuthにTwitchのプロバイダがあるためこれを利用できないかと考えていたのですが、こちらを使えばTwitchでのOIDC認証は可能ですがFirebaseでの認証につなげることができない認識です。
そこで上記の方法を検討したのですが、実装がかなり面倒です。他に手段は存在しないのでしょうか。

2つ目は2の方法で複数回ページが読み込まれるのはNext.jsの仕様なのでしょうか。もし回避方法があればご教授いただきたくよろしくお願いいたします。